# Get all 'Global administrators' users in Azure using python

Tags: python, azure

I want to list all users with the role of 'Global Administrator' in Azure.
I looked in the "AuthorizationManagementClient" and "GraphRbacManagementClient" classes but didn't find how to get this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Python SDK doesn't have any method to achieve your requirement.

However, the other alternative would be to make use of the GRAPH.

You could use the below GRAPH Endpoint :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments?$filter=roleDefinitionId eq '62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10'&$expand=principal
```

ID : 62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10 -- **Company Administrator** (Global Administrator)

For other roles/role id you could refer to this [blog](https://www.easy365manager.com/azure-administrator-roles/) or Run a powershell command `Get-MsolRole | Sort-Object Name | ft Name,ObjectID,description`

The response is a  returns User Collections who are the Company Administrator(Global Administrator)

**Sample Response :**

[image]

You could Python to invoke the Graph Endpoint. You can invoke it directly using the `requests` library or you can use the below library which is a **wrapper of the Graph APIs**

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core

Also, **Note** : You will have to register an Azure app with the below permission

[image]

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-list-roleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)